# How can I prevent Chromium from opening svg files?

Tags: chromium, svg

Chromium keeps opening `svg` files in the browser despite the default association of `Inkscape` with svg files.

Steps to reproduce:

1. Download an svg file
2. Go to `chrome:downloads` and click on the svg file.
3. It opens in Chromium in a new tab instead of Inkscape

Answer (score 0):

Check if the lines below are presents on file:

> sudo nano /usr/share/applications/mimeinfo.cache

```
image/svg+xml=gimp.desktop;inkscape.desktop;eog.desktop;
image/svg+xml-compressed=inkscape.desktop;eog.desktop;
```

Comment: Yes, they are. This does not solve the problem, unfortunately.